# Почему не работает метод Delete?

Tags: php, ооп

подскажите пожалуйста и за чего метод Delete не удаляет пользователя( Для примера показал и метод get - он работает )

**index.php**

```
#$products = Database::getInstance()->get('products', ['name', '=', 'Macbook PRO']);
Database::getInstance()->delete('products', ['name', '=', 'Danu']);
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php


class Database
{

  private static $instance = null;
  private $pdo, $query, $error = false, $results, $count;


  private function __construct()
  {
    try{
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university;", 'mysql', 'mysql');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  public function getInstance(){


    if(!isset(self::$instance)){
      self::$instance = new Database();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }


  public function query($sql, $params=[]){
    $this->error = false;
    $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    if(count($params)){
      $i = 1;
      foreach($params as $param){

        $this->query->bindValue($i, $param);
        $i++;
      }
    }

    if(!$this->query->execute()){
      $this->error = true;
    }
    else{
      $this->results = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();
    }
    return $this;

  }

  public function get($table, $where=[]){

    return $this->action('SELECT', $table, $where);
  }

  public function delete($table, $where=[]){

    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);

  }

  public function action($action, $table, $where){
    if(count($where) === 3){

      $operators = ['=', '>', '<', '<=', '>='];
      $field = $where[0];
      $operator = $where[1];
      $value = $where[2];

      if(in_array($operator, $operators)){

        $sql = "{$action} * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

        if( !$this->query($sql, [$value])->showError() ){
          return $this;
        }
      }

    }
  }



  public function showError()
  {
    return $this->error;
  }

  public function showResult(){
    return $this->results;
  }

  public function count(){


    return $this->count;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом здесь три проблемы - локальная, глобальная и концептуальная.

Тов. Мелкий правильно указывает на первые две, а я обращу внимание на третью.

Смысла в функции Delete - ноль целых, ноль десятых.

Не составляет ни малейшей проблемы написать

```
Database::getInstance()->query('DELETE FROM products WHERE name = ?', ['Danu']);
```

А подводных камней с этим ручным колупанием в запросах - вагон и маленькая тележка.

Ну и в целом у класса много косяков, в частности, хранение результата внутри объекта, что приведет к ошибкам нарушения целостности, когда запрос уже другой, а результат всё тот же. Или приватность свойства $pdo которое не даст воспользоваться свойствами и методами этого класса, например таким банальным как lastInsertId()

Я бы от ввсего класса оставил только метод query, в таком виде

```
public function query($sql, $params=[]){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

и писал просто

```
$products = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = ?', ['Macbook PRO'])->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Я бы не согласился, что смысла в функции Delete ноль. Но скорее всего, я бы порекомендовал использовать библиотеку типа fluentPDO, где есть уже неплохой конструктор запросов.

Comment: Ноль, ноль. Если бы был ORM - то да. А городить функцию просто чтобы сэкономить себе два слова в SQL запросе ничем кроме лени и недальновидности объяснить нельзя

Comment: Спасибо вам за примечание

Answer (score 4):

А почему должен? Выведите полученный SQL-запрос в `$sql`.

```
DELETE * FROM -- дальше уже и не важно
```

Нет такого синтаксиса в стандарте и я не знаю СУБД, где бы такое реализовали расширение стандарта.

Основная ваша проблема в том, что у вас нет обработки ошибок. Поставьте `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` в адекватный `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, тогда `PDO` будет для вас генерировать хорошо заметные `exception`.