# Как получить лишь array?

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

делаю запрос в базу данных для получения по е-майл

```
$user = $this->db->get('products', ['email','=', $email]);
```

Через var_Dump получаю

```
object(Database)#2 (5) { ["pdo":"Database":private]=> object(PDO)#3 (0) { } ["query":"Database":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(38) "SELECT * FROM products WHERE email = ?" } ["error":"Database":private]=> bool(false) ["results":"Database":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "16" ["email"]=> string(12) "danu@mail.ru" ["name"]=> string(4) "Danu" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$plpesxMMJyty6PGqWWkQJefV.tSWAUD.r9rMq6/MYIFUwQfj1jWeq" } } ["count":"Database":private]=> int(1) }
```

Как можно получить лишь array с данными без private, error, select и.т.п

Comment: Наверное надо почитать доки по драйверу БД, который вы используете?

Comment: @СергейМишин так он [сам же этот драйвер и ваяет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1100882/179379) :))) Причем я ему говорил - не нужно городить этот get(), поскольку это экономия на спичках, которая потом выйдет боком. Но у нас же все шибко грамотные, идут своим путём :)

Comment: @Ипатьев дело не в этом я лишь обучаюсь. Знал бы как лучше писал лучше, а пока так:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, я так понимаю что тебя отговорить не получится. Тогда показываю как правильно делать функцию get()

```
public function getRow($sql, $params = [], $mode = PDO::FETCH_OBJ){
    return $this->query($sql, $params)->fetch($mode);
}
public function getArr($sql, $params = [], $mode = PDO::FETCH_OBJ){
    return $this->query($sql, $params)->fetchAll($mode);
}
public function getOne($sql, $params = []){
    return $this->query($sql, $params)->fetchColumn();
}
```

Соответственно, вызов переписать так

```
$user = $this->db->getRow('SELECT * FROM products WHERE email =?', [$email]);
```

- Во-первых, надо выкинуть на помойку твой доморощенный квери билдер, который экономит тебе ажно ЦЕЛЫХ ТРИ СЛОВА в SQL запросе, но зато превращает великолепный язык SQL в жалкого уродца, отрывая ему ноги, руки, голову и остальные выступающие части.
- Во-вторых, нужны ТРИ функции, а не одна, по типам возвращаемых результатов
- В-третьих, надо бережно относиться к тому БОГАТОМУ функционалу, который прдеоставляет ПДО, и не отрывать ему ноги тоже, а дать возможность использовать его в своей поделке.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам

Comment: Я только что подправил код немного

Comment: Да, спасибо вам